# How to change the sentence that is displayed after clicking facebook 'like'

Tags: facebook-like

On creating the facebook application, I hope to change the sentence that is diplayed after clicking the like button.
For example, after cliking the like button, the following sentence is displayed,
"You like http://www.patricktools.com/d/facebook/web/social_plugins01.html."
I need to change it to the below,
"You like patrictools_web."

My any trial can't resolve this problem all day long!
Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Per their [usage guidelines](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php), I don't think you can change it...

> While you may scale the size to suit
>   your needs, you may not modify the
>   Like Button in any other way (such as
>   by changing the design).